# error in clearcase 8.0 :premature eof

Tags: clearcase, clearcase-ucm, cleartool

I Recently installed clear case 8.0 in my laptop both the stand alone and integrated versions (integration with data stage). I created a view using the option "create a view on existing UCM stream". When I select the folders from the project VOB I receive error "Error:

```
"During GET of \vobs\Internal_apps_sub\ISL_ACQ_code\.project: Premature EOF
" Error: "During GET of \vobs\Internal_apps_sub\ISL_ACQ_code\DataStage"
```

for each and every object and eventually folder remains empty. Although I have created the ticket with IBM people to look into the issue, I wondered if anybody faced similar problems while working with clear case 8.0? the view that I have created here is the web view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem got solved. There was issue with the server url that was used to connect with the server. It was not correct owing to which Clear case was not able to properly download the elements from VOBs to my local folder in snapshot view.

Answer (score 1):

While I haven't seen this issue, it has been seen in early versions of CCRC (7.1.x), like [in this technote](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21327153), in case of an integration with another product.

It is generally linked to a timeout parameter which is set too low, and causes the http transaction to end prematurely.

In your case though, IBM support should have a more specific answer.

Comment: Yes I had seen the same link before. One of the guy from clear case is asking me to locate and rename "C:\ProgramData\ibm\Rational.preserve" but If I go to program data folder and IBM I dont see any raetional.preserver folder.

Comment: @NIMISHDESHPANDE may be he/she didn't get your exact version of ClearCase? Or your OS? May be you installed a 32-bits which should then be in `C:\Program Files (x86)`?

Comment: there was a .bat file (present on an network drive) which I had used to install. while the version is 8.0, it seems the installation is 32 bit install on the 64 bit laptop

Comment: @NIMISHDESHPANDE yes, hence my suggestion for `C:\Program Files (x86)`, which is generally where a 32-bits program is installed on a 64-bits Windows.

Comment: one of the IBM guy has responded back wit this reply: “One of the first steps of troubleshooting would be asking another user to log on his machine and try to use CTE.
If that works, it may be an issue related to the user's profile. 
If it doesn't work for the other user, the best and fastest solution would be re-imaging the machine.
“

Comment: @NIMISHDESHPANDE Ok. That seems a bit more radical than "did you try to logoff/logon" ;)

Comment: yeah exactly.. It sounded like.. your computer is not running smoothly.. just format it..